# What's the best way to generically map routes with required parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have several ASP.NET MVC controllers. Many of these take one or more required values (e. g. ids). Because these values are required, I'd like to make them part of the url path rather than query string arguments. For example:

```
// route should be MyController/Action1/[someKindOfId1]
public ActionResult Action1(int someKindOfId1) { ... }

// less commonly:
// route should be MyController/Action1/[someKindOfId2]/[someKindOfId3]
public ActionResult Action2(int someKindOfId2, int someOtherKindOfId3) { ... }
```

I'm looking for a way to Map these routes without manually listing out each one. For example, I currently do:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Action1Route",
    "MyController/Action1/{someKindOfId1}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Action1" }
);
```

Some ways I've considered:
* Use the default {controller}/{action}/{id} route, and just either rename my parameters to id or (not sure if this works) use the [Bind] attribute to allow bind them to the id route value while still having descriptive names. This still restricts me to a common controller/action base URL (not bad, but not the most flexible either as it ties URLs to the current code organization).
* Create an attribute which I could put on action methods to configure their routes. I could then reflect over all controllers and configure routes on application start.

Is there a best-practice/built-in approach for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no. The method you describe is the only way with MVC Routing. If you're not going to use the default (or at least your own version of the default), you must add a separate route for each unique scheme.

However, I would encourage you to check out [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/), which for me at least, is far superior to managing routes in the traditional way. With AttributeRouting, you specify the URL  for each controller action using, appropriately enough, an attribute. For example:

```
[GET("MyController/Action1/{someKindOfId1}")]
public ActionResult Action1(int someKindOfId1) { ... }

[GET("MyController/Action1/{someKindOfId2}/{someKindOfId3}")]
public ActionResult Action2(int someKindOfId2, int someOtherKindOfId3) { ... }
```

Only, you're not bound to using the controller/action route scheme either, so you can do something like:

```
[GET("foo/{someKindOfId1}")]
public ActionResult Action1(int someKindOfId1) { ... }

[GET("foo/{someKindOfId2}/{someKindOfId3}")]
public ActionResult Action2(int someKindOfId2, int someOtherKindOfId3) { ... }
```

And to even better, you can add a `RoutePrefix` attribute to your controller itself to specify a path partial that should apply to all actions in that controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("foo")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [GET("{someKindOfId1}")]
    public ActionResult Action1(int someKindOfId1) { ... }

    [GET("{someKindOfId2}/{someKindOfId3}")]
    public ActionResult Action2(int someKindOfId2, int someOtherKindOfId3) { ... }
}
```

There's support for handling areas, subdomains, etc. as well and you can even type-qualify parameters (e.g. `{someKindOfId1:int}` to make it only match if the URL part is an integer type). Give the documentation a read.

**UPDATE**

It's worth mentioning that ASP.NET 5 now has attribute routing built in. (It's actually using very similar code to AttributeRouting, submitted by the author of that package.) It's not really a good enough reason on its own to upgrade all your projects (since you can just add in the AttributeRouting package to get basically the same functionality), but if you're starting off with a new project, it's definitely nice to have.